# Problem with \split

Tags: amsmath, split

I'm a bit new to latex, and seem to be having a problem with the `\split` function.

I want to split a long equation, and it has worked for all of my other equations, but for this one, it is giving me errors of runaway argument, missing $ insterted, and missing endgroup inserted. How can i solve this?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \frac{\delta\vec{v}}{\delta\vec{w}} & =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{\delta}{\delta\vec{w_0}}{w_0a_0}^{(n)} & \frac{\delta}{\delta\vec{w_1}}{w_0a_0}^{(n)} & \dots & \frac{\delta}{\delta\vec{w_n}}{w_0a_0}^{(n)}\\
        
        \frac{\delta}{\delta\vec{w_0}}{w_1a_1}^{(n)} & \frac{\delta}{\delta\vec{w_1}}{w_1a_1}^{(n)} & \dots & \frac{\delta}{\delta\vec{w_n}}{w_1a_1}^{(n)}\\
        
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        
        \frac{\delta}{\delta\vec{w_0}}{w_na_n}^{(n)} & \frac{\delta}{\delta\vec{w_1}}{w_na_n} & \dots & \frac{\delta}{\delta\vec{w_n}}{w_na_n}
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    & =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        {a_0}^{(n)} & 0 & \dots & 0\\
        0 & {a_1}^{(n)} & \dots & 0\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
        0 & 0 & \dots & {a_n}^{(n)}
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \diag(\vec{a^{(n)}})
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeXSX! I have no problem compiling your (completed) code. Did you load `amsmath`?

Comment: No blank lines are allowed inside `split`. They are allowed in matrices, but only in `equation`, not when the matrix is in alignment environments.